# vbscript regular expression into an array

Tags: regex, arrays, vbscript

With the code below I am trying to pull each url I extract using the regular expression into an array that I can call later along with the count of urls. Not sure how to grab all of them.

```
Set objxmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Call objxmlHTTP.open("GET", "website", False)
objxmlHTTP.Send()

strHTML = objxmlHTTP.ResponseText

Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "<a\s+href=""(http://.*?)""[^>]+>(\s*\n|.+?\s*)</a>"

Dim objMatch
For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strHTML)
  objMatch.SubMatches(0)
Next

Set objxmlHTTP = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with a fake string, your regexp results seemed a bit wonky so I changed it (grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261136/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link)). Results of the 1st match (you capture 2?) are placed in the matches array:

```
Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = ""((https?:\/\/|www.)([-\w.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)""

dim matches()
dim i: i = 0

Dim objMatch
For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strHTML)
   redim preserve matches(i)
   matches(i) = objMatch.SubMatches(0)
   i = (i + 1)
Next

Set objxmlHTTP = Nothing

'//read back
for i = 0 to ubound(matches)
   wscript.echo matches(i)
next
```